# Scale out methods with high availability

Tags: sql-server, performance, high-availability, scalability

We have a two site AlwaysOn Cluster and looking to do a High Available multi-site write solution. We have looked at Replication, Sharding, and SQL Elastic options for having multi-site write for a single application. End goal is to have N number of sites that can host the application closest to the user requesting the service, with high availability. We have scaled up, now we want to scale out.

It looks like sharding might be the best option. Does anyone have solid experience with implementing a solution like this in MS SQL?

Comment: Also see [Is it possible to scale-out with Microsoft SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200189/is-it-possible-to-scale-out-with-microsoft-sql-server) and [Scaling out SQL Server and syncing data across multiple machines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65558/scaling-out-sql-server-and-syncing-data-across-multiple-machines)

Comment: Are you writing more than you're reading? Scaling reads is far, far, far easier (and usually a much higher priority) than scaling writes.